# How to sort lines of a string in Swift?

Tags: arrays, string, swift, sorting

I have a textView where I enter text, I would like to programmatically sort lines (intended here as chunks of text separated by a newline). For example:

```
Bravo
27
Charlie
Zulu
delta
012
Alfa
bravo
Delta
```

I'm trying to convert the tex to an array, then sort the array and then joying the array in a new string. Unfortunately I get unexpected results, for example words with capital letters are grouped at the beginning of the list, the ones with lowercase are listed at the end.

This is the code I'm using:

```
let newStr = (the field) // pseudocode

let strArray : [String] = newStr.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
let newArray = strArray.sort { $0 < $1 }
newStr = newArray.joinWithSeparator("\n")

(the field) = newStr // pseudocode
```

EDIT: the result I would like to get, would be to have a sorted list taking into account local settings. In my case, for example, would be:

```
012
27
Alfa
bravo
Bravo
Charlie
delta
Delta
Zulu
```

Comment: why is that unexpected? have you read about string sorting and how it works? you also haven't specified how you would like your sample data to appear in the result...

Comment: Do you understand that alphabetical ordering is intentionally case sensitive in some languages?

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I edited the question.

Comment: Is this limited to English?

Comment: Hi, my goal would be to have a sorted list taking into account local settings

Comment: @Tel Localization adds an extra layer of complexity I think. So I guess it's best to leave that for now. One way to sort through this is by breaking the problem down. First you'd like to break the text separately int an array right?

Comment: You're going to need something to store that data. And somewhere to keep track of number of words. There's kind of a lot at play here when you break it down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would solve this problem by changing your sort code to

```
let newArray = strArray.sort{$0.localizedCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending}
```

From Apple Documentation:

> **Important**: For user-visible sorted lists, you should *always* use localized comparisons. Thus typically instead of `compare:` or `caseInsensitiveCompare:` you should use `localizedCompare:` or `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html)